# Adding dynamic data to Html table ? Using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using, j query to bind the data to html table it is working fine, but the thing is, in the html table showing one extra column with the project name and class name. How can i avoid this, help me, i am placing my code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<Mystate> GetCountryList()
    {
        List<Mystate> state = new List<Mystate>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxx"].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_get_data", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(); da.Fill(ds);


        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
        {
            state.Add(new Mystate { Districtid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["distid"]), Stateid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["stateid"]), Distrinctname = dr["districtname"] .ToString ()});
        }


        return state;
    }
```

Javascript Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnin').click(function () {

            $.ajax({

                url: "TableJquery.aspx/GetCountryList",
                data: "",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });

        });//button click

    });//Ready

    function OnSuccess(data) {            

        $('#Div2').html(BuildTable(data));             

    }

    function BuildTable(data) {

        var d = data.d;

        var headers = [];
        var rows = [];

        //column                       

        headers.push("<tr style='background-color:brown;'>");
        for (var column in d[0]) {               
                headers.push("<td ><b>" + column + "</b></td>");                  
        }
        headers.push("</tr>");


        // Rows

            for (var row in d) {
                rows.push("<tr>");
               // rows.push("<td><input type='button'   value='+' /></td>");
                for (var column in d[row]) {
                    if (d[row][column] != 'Divcenterformasterpage.Mystate') {
                        rows.push("<td>");
                        rows.push(d[row][column]);
                        rows.push("</td>");
                    }
                }
                rows.push("</tr>");
            }

            var top = "<table border='1' style='background-color:;' >";
            var bottom = "</table>";
            return top + headers.join("") + rows.join("") + bottom;


    }
```

My table coming with the extra column "Divcenterformasterpage.Mystate",  which is my project name and "Mystate" is the calss. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch your  `for (var row in d)` Loop by `for (var i= 0;i< d.count;i++)`.
It will work fine.